# Missing vertices when skinning

Tags: rigging, vertices

I am trying to skin my creature and I can skin one side. However, the other side doesn't have the vertices and I am not sure how to get them or what when wrong. I parented the bones to the creature and then hit box mode to select the areas where need skinned, but I cannot select one entire side. I attached an image for it to be seen.

Thanks in advance![image]

Comment: you should apply the mirror modifier first

Comment: What should I do that before? Trying to skin it?

Comment: because the other half is a reflection ( not real vertices yet ) they do whatever the other half do

Comment: Ah I see. So when do I add the modifier? And how? Should I select the vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the properties window.
Select the modifiers tab.
Apply the mirror modifier.
Then you can do the skinning.

[image]